# Unable to collect metrics on my Geth node using default port 6060

Tags: go-ethereum

I am interested in collecting metrics on my geth node (working towards getting a Grafana dashboard), but I'm currently unable to see stats when browsing to `http://NodeIpAddress:6060/debug/metrics`.

I followed instructions on the [Ethereum blog post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/07/10/geth-v1-9-0/) and have added two new flags `--metrics --pprof` to my startup script, which should put it on default port `6060`.

Upon restarting my node, I see `Enabling metrics collection` in the logs, and no obvious errors.

Since I'm running on Ubuntu server, I have opened up my firewall on port 6060 using this command `sudo ufw allow 6060/tcp` and see via `netstat` that geth is listening on port 6060.

Unfortunately, when browsing to `http://NodeIpAddress:6060/debug/metrics`, I see an error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Any ideas what else I can do besides opening firewall to allow this connection?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this one out. Turns out my metrics were publishing, but because I was connecting from a remote host, that device was unable to browse to the metrics. This can be resolved by adding a couple flags to your geth start script:
`--metrics.addr 0.0.0.0 --pprof.addr 0.0.0.0`
The purpose of 0.0.0.0 is to whitelist any requesting IP. You may change this value if you'd like to restrict access to devices, say, only on your subnet.